Excel: How to select a chart's data range using a corresponding value in another cell?
Let's say a DataSheet has the following data that is subject to change, including date headers. The number of columns is always the same. (Top left cell is A1.)



Name
Dec 1
Dec 2
Dec 3
Dec 4
Dec 5
...
Dec 23




Dallas
3
4
3
2
3
...
2


Kane
6
5
5
4
4
...
7


Ripley
5
8
7
9
7
...
6



In SummarySheet there is a single column of the same names, and they are separated by multiple rows to allow space for charts for each individual name.
Each chart's data range contains the headers and a specific row. Here is the range for Ripley:
=DataSheet!$A$1:$X$1,DataSheet!$B$4:$X$4
Is there a formula that can use the names in the SummarySheet!A:A column to obtain the corresponding data from DataSheet? Perhaps a lookup, filter, or offset? I have not been able to get anything to work yet.
(I expect the charts to have formulas that differ only in their references to SummarySheet!A cells. Then I would not need to touch the charts ever again.)
(The names and data will be renewed every time I remake (copy and repopulate) the workbook. I would rather not have to manually change the charts' data ranges for hundreds of names multiple times per year.)

I am not clear on this. Posting a file may help more.
I am guessing that the names in the SummarySheet are the column header's names, right?
So then these would be used to select the second row delineated in the formula that starts with =DataSheet. Right?
I am also thinking that allotting blank rows in Column A of SummarySheet would just add another layer of complexity to your work. I'd put the names in consecutive rows and get the charts to work first, then think about spacing.

I stated the names are the same, yes. There is no added complexity with empty rows; each chart will need to be configured manually anyway. Just focus on one.
